# using pointer and address operator together

Tags: c++, pointers

I couldnt understand the why we are using *&first (pointer and address operator together).
What does it mean? And when should i use it?

```
void splitArray (int *A, int size, int ind1, int ind2, int *&first, int &firstSize,int *&second, int &secondSize)
{
    firstSize = ind2 - ind1 + 1;
    secondSize = size - firstSize;

    first = new int[firstSize];
    second = new int[secondSize];

    int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ((i >= ind1) && (i <= ind2)){
        first[cnt1] = A[i]; 
        cnt1++;
    }
    else 
        {
    second[cnt2] = A[i]; 
    cnt2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean? And when should i use it?

The `&` symbol appearing after a *type* defines a *reference* to that type. Thus, for instance, `int&` is a reference to an `int`, `my_object&` is a reference to `my_object`, and `int *&` is a reference to an `int*` (i.e. a reference to a pointer to an `int`).

When it appears in a function signature, that means the corresponding argument will be passed by reference rather than by value: when passing by value, the function receives a *copy* of the argument; when passing by reference, on the other hand, the function operates directly on the argument being passed.

Therefore, passing a pointer by reference means that changes done by the function to the value of that pointer will affect the original argument being passed.

In particular, these two instructions:

```
first = new int[firstSize];
second = new int[secondSize];
```

Will assign a dynamically allocated array to `first` and `second`. Therefore, in the following code snippet (ellipses represent other arguments):

```
int* myfirst = NULL;
int* mysecond = NULL;
splitArray(..., myfirst, ..., mysecond, ...);
```

When returning from `splitArray()`, `myfirst` and `mysecond` will point to the arrays allocated inside the functions and assigned to `first` and `second`, respectively.

If you weren't passing those pointers by reference, then the value of `myfirst` and `mysecond` would still be `NULL` after `splitArray()` returns (because `splitArray()` would be working on a *copy* of those pointers).

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer that is being passed by reference. This means that when `first` is changed:

```
first = new int[firstSize];
```

the change propagates back to the caller.

Fundamentally, this is no different to how `firstSize` is being passed around, except that `first` happens to be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

& considers everything in front of it as type to reference. Sometimes you need to pass pointer itself not the copy of it. For example, you may need to allocate memory in a function that will be used out of it. So you pass pointer as reference to be able to handle it but not the address it points.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, programmers use references to be sure that the pointer object exist at the moment to initialize the object, before the rest of the implementation of the object included constructor instructions.